# align datepicker div on hover and select

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

http://jsbin.com/gusogohe/8

On the above link is my code, where I have tried to make the datepicker div to follow the hover of mouse button on a tags. But I do not seem to get it work correctly. What i need is to make a div containing the datepicker right next to the a tag on hover and also to make possible to choose a date and execute a function while on a particular div.

Can someone help me achieve this.
Thanks.

Update:
Thanks for your answers. Could you please also tell how can I also get the reference of the a tag for which the date was selected? I mean how do I know on the datapickers onSelect function the a tag where the calendar was when date was choosen.

Update2:
I got it.
console.log(selectedDate+" "+$(this).parent("div").attr("id"));
Gets the parent div when date was choosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

appendTo must take `this` as argument. Here is the solution: http://jsbin.com/gusogohe/9/

Answer (score 1):

Although you can change this:

```
var x = $(this).attr('id');
```

to this:

```
var x = '#'+$(this).attr('id');
```

or:

```
var x = '#'+this.id;
```

---

Because you are targeting `id` to append and `#` is the prefix for ID selector in jQuery.

---

```
$( "#datepicker" ).appendTo(this);
```

You can pass the current context as passing `this` in the `.appendTo()`.